# Access 2013 32bit Crashes in Windows 7 but not Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-7, crash, 32-bit, microsoft-access-2013

I converted a 97 Access database to Access 2013 32bit.
The database now crashes in Windows 7 but works fine in Windows 2012 R2.

If I copy the database to the PC, the first time the database is opened, it won't crash but it'll will crash everytime after.

This query will always crash Access in Windows 7 but not Windows Server 2012:

```
UPDATE BatchHdr SET BatchHdr.RecCount = Val(Nz(DCount("[EntryID]","BatchDtl","[BatchID] = " & [BatchID]),0)), BatchHdr.Errors = Val(Nz(DCount("[EntryID]","BatchDtl","[Er] is not null and [BatchID]=" & [BatchID]),0)), BatchHdr.Warnings = Val(Nz(DCount("[EntryID]","BatchDtl","[Warning] is not null and [BatchID]=" & [BatchID]),0)), BatchHdr.NeedsChecked = IIf(DCount("[BatchID]","BatchDtl","[Checked] = false and [BatchID] = " & [BatchID])>0,True,False) WHERE (((BatchHdr.Status)<>"Exported" And (BatchHdr.Status)=[Forms]![BatchHeader]![MyStatus])) WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION;
```

I can't figure out how to make this database work in Windows 7. I've tried running Access in compatibility mode and it'll not crash initially but will after 1-2 opens.

Access 32bit must be used due to 32bit vba code being used.

I receive an error msg:

```
APP NAME: MSACCESS.EXE
FAULT MODULE: OLEAUT32.DLL
FAULT MODULE VERSION: 6.1.7601.18679
EXCEPTION CODE: C0000005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound's like it could be a cache issue that windows 7 can't handle.

I found a guide [here](http://ccm.net/faq/17102-access-clear-cache-on-exit) that explains how to clear access cache on close.

1. Click on File > Options > Current Database
2. Scroll to the "Caching Web Services and Sharepoints table"
3. Check "Use the cache format that is compatible with Microsoft Access 2010 and later"
4. Check "Clear Cache on Close"
5. Click "OK"
6. Restart Access for the changes to take effect.

This should prevent Access from crashing when it opens or reopens.